# XSLT condition in for each loop does not extract the correct nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I am having fetching the node which meet the conditions as specified in the XSLT.

I want to select PID.5.1,PID.5.2,PID.5.3 if PID.5.7 ="L" 
so i want the resut to fetch - FN1,GN1 and MN1.

I have XML file which looks like below, "PID.5" can be 1 to n.

Please help.

My XML input:

```
<PID>
    <PID5PTName>
        <FN>
            <FSN> FN1 <FSN>
        </FN1>
        <FGN> GN1 <FSN>
        <FMN> MN1 <FMN>
        <FNCode> L <FNCode>
    </PID5PTName>

    <PID5PTName>
        <FN>
            <FSN> FN2 <FSN>
        </FN>
        <FGN> GN2 <FGN>
        <FMN> MN2 <FMN>
        <FNCode> M <FNCode>
    </PID5PTName>

    <PID5PTName>
        <FN>
            <FSN> FN3 <FSN>
        </FN>
        <FGN> GN3 <FGN>
        <FMN> MN3 <FMN>
        <FNCode> A <FNCode>
    </PID5PTName>
</PID>
```

My XSLT solution looks like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//PID/PID5PTName">

                <xsl:for-each select="FNCode">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test=".='L'">
                                  <xsl:attribute name="First">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="../../FSN/>
                                  </xsl:attribute>
                                <xsl:attribute name="Middle">
                                  <xsl:value-of select="../../FMN"/>
                                </xsl:attribute>
                                  <xsl:attribute name="Last">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="../../FGN"/>
                                  </xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose> 
                </xsl:for-each>

            </xsl:for-each>
```

Result I am getting: GN1,**MN1**,FN1. It works fine but not in all scenarios for example:

If first "PID.5" node do not have node- "PID.5.3", I get the result: GN1,**MN2**,FN1; which is incorrect

The desired result in this case is GN1,FN1.

Any suggestions as what is wrong with my XSLT is greatly appreciated.

Comment: -1 Please let us know where did you struck while implementing this change. Your requirement is not clear. Please update the question clearly.

Comment: I apologized for not putting enough details in first attempt. I have added more details now. Thanks.

Comment: The XSLT you've posted is not consistent with the output you say you're getting - there's a second layer of `PID.5` elements in between the `PID/PID.5` and the `PID.5.7` (so the inner `for-each` wouldn't select anything) and then once you get to the `PID.5.7` the relative path from there to the other fields would be `..` rather than `../..`.

Comment: Thanks Ian for your response. I have corrected my XML input. Please  suggest. Thanks again.

Comment: In addition, the posted XML isn't valid - there are many nodes without the appropriate closing tag and mixed node-names, e.g. the node <FGN> GN2 <FSN> should be <FGN> GN2 </FGN> and so on. But I guess that's not the XML you're really working with but kind of copy-pasted example to get an idea of the requirement.

Comment: any more suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Though the question is a bit unclear I just want to add a small template providing a possible solution to get the desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><xsl:stylesheet 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="1.0">
 <xsl:template match="/*">
 <xsl:for-each select="
  //*[text()='L']/parent::*/node()/text()[not (self::text()='L')]">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
   <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Output (working with an online XSLT-Generator):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>FN1,GN1,MN1
```

Possible to omit the xml declaration and to get rid of the "," between the values (just added them as an extra).
Maybe this could be of help for getting the right solution as I think question is how to get the values of the previous siblings from the node with the text 'L'.
Using an `xsl:for-each` loop, select as starting point the node which has the `text()='L'`, go up to this node's parent with `/parent::`, select from there all text from the child nodes excluding the 'L' with

```
*/node()/text()[not (self::text()='L')]
```

and you have the values. Don't know about further processing requirements, but hope that helps to get in the right direction.

Update: as XML provided in the question was changed, above example won't work anymore with the question's current XML.

Comment: Can you please look at the my solution and see what is wrong?

Comment: @user3400087 Just to be sure - you already tried to work with suggested solution for your template? Advantage would be that you would just select the children of the parent of the node with text-value L excluding the L-node, not having to care about the amount. When you want to adjust the template in your updated question, it would be possible to add checking if the FSN, FGM, FMN - nodes are children of the same parent as the L-node. Otherwise you get the values mixed up because your template is looking for nodes by name, not caring about their relative position.